# How To Create A Stacked List Of Photo Profiles

Tags: android

How do I create stacked profile pictures like below? Is it a trick using RecyclerView or something similar?

**EDIT:** I'm sorry that I didn't described my problem completely. So, I need to create this using an ArrayList. So the amount of images is dynamic.

[image: this]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for stacked list of profile pic

```
 <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rl_1"
          android:layout_width="60dp"
          android:layout_height="60dp">
         <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
             android:id="@+id/civ_1"
             android:layout_width="60dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
             app:civ_circle_background_color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
             android:src="@drawable/doctor"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
      </RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rl_2"
          android:layout_width="60dp"
          android:layout_height="60dp"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rl_1"
          android:layout_marginStart="-30dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp">
         <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
             android:id="@+id/civ_2"
             android:layout_width="60dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
             app:civ_circle_background_color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
             android:src="@drawable/doctor"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
      </RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rl_3"
          android:layout_width="60dp"
          android:layout_height="60dp"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rl_2"
          android:layout_marginStart="-30dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp">
         <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
             android:id="@+id/civ_3"
             android:layout_width="60dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
             app:civ_circle_background_color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
             android:src="@drawable/doctor"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
         <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:src="@drawable/bg_trans"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="1+"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="18sp"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

You can change size of images, color according to your need.

Output for above code is:

[image]

I hope it works for you.

Comment: hi, I'm sorry that I didn't describe my problem completely. But I need to create this using recyclerview or something because the amount of images is dynamic (using ArrayList). Do you have any ideas? Thanks.